# Converting JSON to POJO using Jackson 'No suitable constructor found for type'

Tags: rest, jackson

Trying to convert JSON to POJO using Jackson for my rest API. However, I'm not allowed to alter the object classes. One of the services consumes -

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "adds",
        "key": "adds"
    },
    "role": {
        "example1": "adds",
        "example12": "adds"
    }
}
```

However, the PUT method only accepts one object; therefore, I have combined this into a single object `UserRole`. Now I'm trying to `deserialise` this into a Java object.

Comment: Anything wrong with just using JSON.parse()? Never mind, I read the "J" as javascript. :-)

Comment: I encountered this error when used an inner class that is not static. is this the case?

Comment: Agree with Sharonbn's comment. It is usually due to the missing "Static" in the inner class.